# How to clear an array and reset the values in a for loop while building a Json string?

Tags: python, json, list, for-loop, openpyxl

I am looping through each row in an excel sheet using the openpyxl import to ultimately build a large Json string that i can feed to an API.

I am looping through each row and building out my json structure, I need to split a cell value by " || " and then for each value it needs to be added as a nested array inside a json section. I currently am using the following code and my problem is that I build my list object in my for loop and append the json chunk to a larger array and it keeps appending my list values during each loop. So i used the .Clear() method on the list to clear it after each loop...but then when i compile my final output my list is empty. Its like it does not maintain its values when it is added to the list each loop. I am new to Python and gave it a good whirl. Any suggestions in the right direction would be appreciated. Its almost like each loop needs its own unique array to use and keep the values. The tags section of the Json is emptied in the final output for each json line...when it should have the values for each unique iteration in it.

My Data Set (i have 3 rows in excel). You can see that i have values that i want to split in the 7th column. That is the column i am looping through to split the values as they will be nested in my json.

Row 1 (cells) = "ABC","Testing","Testing Again","DATE","DATE",Empty,"A || B || C".

Row 2 (cells) = "ABC 2","Testing 2","Testing Again 2","DATE","DATE",Empty,"X || Y || Z".

Row 3 (cells) = "ABC 3","Testing 3","Testing Again 3","DATE","DATE",Empty,Empty.

**My Code.**

```
#from openpyxl import Workbook
import json
from openpyxl import load_workbook

output_table = input_table.copy()

var_path_excel_file = flow_variables['Location']

workbook = load_workbook(filename=var_path_excel_file)
sheet = workbook.active

#create a null value to be used
emptyString = "Null"

#list out all of the sections of the json that we want to print out - these are based on the inputs
jsonFull = []
jsondata = {}
tags = []

for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=0,max_col=40,values_only=True):  

    #I add my split values to an array so that way when i add the array to the json it will have the proper brackets i need for the API to run correctly
    if value[6] is not None:
        data = value[6].split(" || ")
        for temp in data:           
            tags.append(temp)           

    #I build out the json structure here that will be added for each excel row basically
    jsondata = {
        "name": value[0],
        "short_description": value[1],
        "long_description": value[2],
        "effective_start_date": value[3],
        "effective_end_date": value[4],
        "workflow_state": emptyString,              
        "tags": tags
        }

    #Add the jsondata row to the larger collection
    jsonFull.append(jsondata)   
    tags.clear()

print(json.dumps(jsonFull))
```

And then my desired outcome would be something like this. I just need to figure out the proper syntax for the list handling...and can't seem to find an example to base off of.

```
[
    {
        "name": "ABC", 
        "short_description": "Testing", 
        "long_description": "Testing Again", 
        "effective_start_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "effective_end_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "workflow_state": "Null", 
        "tags": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name": "ABC 2", 
        "short_description": "Testing 2", 
        "long_description": "Testing Again 2", 
        "effective_start_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "effective_end_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "workflow_state": "Null", 
        "tags": [
            "X",
            "Y",
            "Z"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name": "ABC 3", 
        "short_description": "Testing 3", 
        "long_description": "Testing Again 3", 
        "effective_start_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "effective_end_date": "2020-03-04T14:45:22Z", 
        "workflow_state": "Null", 
        "tags": [           
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making a copy of `tags` when you put it into the dictionary or call `tags.clear()`, you're just putting a reference to the same list. You need to create a new list at the beginning of each loop iteration, not reuse the same list.

```
for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=0,max_col=40,values_only=True):  

    #I add my split values to an array so that way when i add the array to the json it will have the proper brackets i need for the API to run correctly
    if value[6] is not None:
        tags = value[6].split(" || ")
    else:
        tags = []         

    #I build out the json structure here that will be added for each excel row basically
    jsondata = {
        "name": value[0],
        "short_description": value[1],
        "long_description": value[2],
        "effective_start_date": value[3],
        "effective_end_date": value[4],
        "workflow_state": emptyString,              
        "tags": tags
        }

    #Add the jsondata row to the larger collection
    jsonFull.append(jsondata)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what i needed!!! Your my hero!!! Thank you for the quick response.